# Constantly refresh Javascript values of text fields

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an input form, and I have a Javascript function that gets all of the field values when you press a button. I am looking for a way to *automatically* refresh the Javascript values (so I can, for example, check if a username is too short on a registration page as they type, and also check if the username is available). Would this be possible?

To clarify, I have an HTML input field (for text), and as the user is typing a result, automatically update.

I'm also open to using PHP or jQuery if it's not possible using solely Javascript, but I'd prefer Javascript if it's possible. Also, sorry if this is a rather basic question, but I've searched and searched and can't find anything on it. I know it's possible because I've seen it on websites (in fact, even on this one, as you type a question, it updates the preview at the bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No jQuery needed

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp="validate(this.value);">

function validate(value){
    //validate code on value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use JQuery Validation Plugin to reduce the heavy checking.
Check this one out at http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Answer (score 1):

You should monitor onkeyup event

```
<input type="text" id="test">

$('#test').on('keyup', function() { //this function is triggered every time the user releases a key while typing inside the text field above
    //do whatever you want here
});
```

Comment: Is that just normal Javascript, or is it jQuery? I ask because I don't recognize the `$` phrase. As you can probably tell, I am new to this language.

Comment: That's jQuery. Regular JS is a bit more complex here, as different browsers use different functions to bind events.

Comment: Here's how you do it without jQuery: http://www.creativemeat.com/development/2012-01-10-oneupweb-cross-browser-event-binding-without-jquery/